# Go to last used row from row x onwards, ignore blanks?

Tags: vba, excel

When a user clicks a cell, I want to take the user to the last used row in the spreadsheet from row 5 onwards.

For some reason this doesn't work and produces a method range of object worksheet failed error.

Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = Range("AB2").Column Then
        Range("A4" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: try this instead `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select`. And your code only works if someone clicks in column AB

Comment: @Peh thanks i have already tried this but it takes the user to row 2. I need it to take the user to the last used row from row 5 down

Comment: This can only happen because the last used row in column A is row 2. Or I don't understand. Do you mean go to last used row but at least go to row 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would jump to the last used row but at least to row 5

```
    If Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row < 5 Then
        Range("A5").Select
    Else
        Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
    End If
```

Answer (score 2):

The last row in a sheet is at the bottom right corner of its `UsedRange` so:

```
[a1].SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
```

will find the last row.